# Estimating normals of pointcloud with open3d

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds, normals, open3d

I need pointcloud with normals and found this tutorial http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.7.0/tutorial/Basic/pointcloud.html#voxel-downsampling
Authors firstly did `voxel_down_sample()` then estimated normals with function `estimate_normals()`. But actually without `voxel_down_sample()` we can find normals with function `estimate_normals()`. The most important thing using these functions shouldn't affect to data itself. So which option is safe? Why did the authors apply `voxel_down_sample()` firstly? Is it enough just to use `estimate_normals()` in order to find normals correctly and without losing and damaging data? What good and workable methods in any programming languages could you suggest in order to estimate normals of the pointcloud?

Answer (score 1):

All point cloud sensors, including Lidar, have an **inherent noise** during its measurement process. In particular, it is highly probable that the sensed point cloud will be significantly influenced by the **quality of the sensor** and the **measuring technique** of the observer if a specific place, such as in given tutorial, is given to the point cloud sensor.
Data pre-processing is crucial since original raw data will be noise-perturbed, non-uniform, and inconsistent. Without preprocessing you won't be able to obtain the precise value that you need, such as normal.

Personally, I think that the `voxel_down_sample()` in a given tutorial is a component of this **preparation**. You may somewhat mitigate the noise in the process, in addition to uniformizing the raw point cloud by sampling the points based on a specific grid interval. Or it might be used to alleviate computational complexity because the input point cloud was overly dense.

Of course, you may achieve the desired result even if you use `estimate_normals()` immediately without downsampling. However, I recommend you to go through some pre-processing procedure that meets the properties of your data for future analysis.

In the case of normal estimation, the procedure is **nearly identical** in other languages or libraries such as *matlab*, *pcl*, and so on. For example, for a particular *o3d* library, the neighborhood for normal estimation is derived by ball query sampling method, whereas matlab's `pcnormals` use knn query. The main difference lies in neighborhood sampling method, and its specific hyperparameters should be tuned based on your data. What really matters will be the data that you use, not the estimation method. You may freely use a method that best meets your environmental circumstances.